# Cypress в режиме headless chrome: Error: read ECONNRESET at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27)

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, тестирование, cypress

Обновил Ubuntu (23.04, ядро Linux 6.2.0-32-generic) и Chrome (117 версия), и перестала работать команда `cypress run` с параметрами `--headless --browser chrome`. С версией Chrome 115 проблем не возникало, но, возможно, что дело может быть и в обновлениях ОС.

Запускаю: `yarn cypress run --headless --browser chrome --spec path/to/mytest.spec.js` и получаю ошибку:

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27)
 {
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

На просторах Сети не нашёл внятного ответа, буду благодарен за любую подсказку или совет, куда копать.

**Окружение**:
Ubuntu: 23.04, Linux 6.2.0-32-generic
Cypress: v6.8.0
Chrome: v117
NodeJS: 18.16.1
NVM: v0.39.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по [этому ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77172708/6398233), такое поведение является [багом в браузере Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1483163) и в настоящий момент в версии 117.0.5938.132 для Linux этот баг исправлен.